# Linking with libtcmalloc ubuntu

Tags: gcc, tcmalloc

I had installed the package **libtcmalloc-minimal0**

but when I try to compile my program with flag

**-ltcmalloc-minimal0**

I am getting error

**/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltcmalloc_minimal0**

I had checked /usr/lib and the library is there

More Info

dpkg gives following o/p

```
dpkg -L libtcmalloc-minimal0
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal_debug.so.0.0.0
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libtcmalloc-minimal0
/usr/share/doc/libtcmalloc-minimal0/TODO
/usr/share/doc/libtcmalloc-minimal0/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/libtcmalloc-minimal0/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libtcmalloc-minimal0/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/libtcmalloc-minimal0/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/libtcmalloc-minimal0/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.0
/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal_debug.so.0
```

and I am compiling for 64 bit mode

and library is also 64 bit

```
file  /usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.0.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

Comment: Is it called exactly `/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal0.so`? Is the library for the right architecture? (you could be compiling in 64-bits mode, whereas the library you installed is 32-bits)

Comment: both library and program is 64 bit mode

Comment: So what part of the code would require libtcmalloc-minimal? Does new/delete statement require it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't link simply to a file with `-l` if it doesn't end exactly with `.so`, since the linker assumes a particular naming convention (`lib*.so`).

You have several choices:

- Install `libtcmalloc-minimal0-dev` if it exists, which should provide the `.so` dynamic link.
- Create the symlink yourself: `cd /usr/lib; ln -s libtcmalloc_minimal.so.0.0.0 libtcmalloc_minimal.so; cd -`
- Link directly to the library without the symlink by using `gcc test.c /usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.0.0.0`
- Link using the `-l` option using the full name: `-l:libtcmalloc_minimal.so.0.0.0`

Comment: So what part of the code would require libtcmalloc-minimal? Does new/delete statements require it?

Answer (score 0):

Running `dpkg -L libtcmalloc-minimal0` will show you that the library is `/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.0` so the correct option should be `-ltcmalloc_minimal` **without any digit**

Comment: same error with ltcmalloc_minimal
see the edit to see dpkg o/p

Comment: perhaps you need to run `ldconfig`. To understand what `gcc` is doing, pass it the `-v` flag.